# ElementTree.parse runs out of memory

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following simple Python script used as a post-export test to verify the exported XML is valid.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

try:
    ElementTree.parse(args[0])
except ElementTree.ParseError as e:
    raise Exception('%s does not contain valid XML.' % args[0])
```

The VM which the script runs out however appears to run out of memory with the latest export file, which is about 88Mb in size.

Running the same script against the same file on my local workstation however parses the file in about 30 seconds without error.

The XML itself is not particularly deep, I think the maximum depth is about 4 levels. However the list is fairly long, at 38,570 items. As a result, I'm thinking there's probably a much more efficient way of parsing this, since I have no desire to store or handle the result of the parsing, I simply want to make sure the XML is valid.

Comment: 88mb is not a large file.  I believe Python supports stream (event-based) parsing with SAX, which would reduce the memory requirements significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Python, but I suggest checking what type of parser `ElementTree.parse` uses.

If it's a DOM parser, try to find a SAX parser and use that instead. SAX parsers are more efficient as they don't store the entire DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll post my solution into your answer

Comment: Looks like my solution I added in to your answer was not acceptable. Not sure how to convey my solution since I've been separately advised that it's not good practice to update my question with the final solution either... Anyway, I adapted this code: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Sax

Comment: The link in your comment should be enough to help anyone else with the same problem. Good to know you got it working.